# Git clone over http keeps asking for username and password, but not at work

Tags: git, github, ssh, github-for-windows

At work we have GitHub Enterprise, and at home just regular GitHub.

At work even when I clone through **http** and **not ssh**, whenever I commit, it **never** asks me for my username or password.

At home, I must use ssh in order to do this, but with http, it always asks me for it.

It never asks me at work, is this because of GitHub enterprise, or because they have stored the username and password somewhere so git always knows?

If the latter is the case, how can I do this on my PC?

Thanks

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/5343068/1264061

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there a way to skip password typing when using https:// on GitHub?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5343068/is-there-a-way-to-skip-password-typing-when-using-https-on-github)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At home, try and cache your https credentials with a [credential helper](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Credential-Storage).

On Windows:

```
git config credential.helper manager
```

That will use the Windows Credentials Manager to cache them.